# WP Admin Bar no longer appears in Dashboard

Tags: wp-admin

The admin bar no longer appears in the dashboard.

1. I have looked through the child theme and there is no code related to the admin bar. The site runs Flatsome (latest theme version) + custom child theme
2. I have enabled troubleshooting mode, disabled all plugins, enabled 2023 Wordpress default theme, but the admin bar does not come back
3. Checked the admin profile, where the bar is enabled. No other admins see the bar either.

It is not loading in the HTML:
[image]

On other sites of mine it shows up right under the wpcontent div.

Nothing in the console appears to be related.

What else can I check?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned there aren't any issues related to the installed plugins, you should check your current user settings under `Users > Your Profile`:

[image]

Furthermore, you should search for admin bar removal on your parent & child theme sources that could be implemented,

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

OR

show_admin_bar(false);
```

For more information, read [this article](https://qodeinteractive.com/magazine/wordpress-admin-bar) and get more clues.